# Configuration of stylelint in Gruntfile

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, postcss, stylelint

I'm trying to create a separate task called stylelint because for reasons I do not want it to be part of the postcss task.

In the gruntfile I'm writing:

```
stylelint: {
  options: {},
  src: './assets/css/precss/**'
}
```

When I run `grunt stylelint` it lints my code but when it finds an issue then I get `Warning: Task "stylelint:src" failed. Use --force to continue.`

Am I omitting something?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [grunt-stylelint](https://github.com/wikimedia/grunt-stylelint) rather than PostCSS as it supports the native stylelint format reporters. Your Gruntfile config should then look something like this:

```
    stylelint: {
        css: {
            options: {
                configFile: '.stylelintrc',
                format: 'css'
            },
            src: [ 'assets/*.css' ]
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that this is not possible. You have to run grunt with --force